# Transform String to StringContext to evaluate deferred

Tags: scala

In Scala 2.10 there exists the `StringContext`. With this you can do something linke this:

```
val x = 10
val y = s"Using $x within this String."
```

Now is `y == "Using 10 within this String."`

But I'd like to apply "s" deferred on a predefined String. I'd like to do something like this:

```
val str = "Using $x within this String."
def foo(arg: String) = {
  // do stuff
  val x = 11
  s"$arg"  // enable the arg-String to use the context
}
```

Now should `foo(str) == "Using 11 within this String."`

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a method instead of a val for this:

```
def str(x: Int) = s"Using $x within this String."

str(11)
```

edit:

Passing the not yet interpolated string around and fill in the argument somewhere else is not possible. Interpolation happens at compile time, so the variable has to be in scope at definition of the string.

Comment: I'd like to pass the String around e.g. as message between Actors.

Comment: You mean pass the not yet interpolated string around and fill in the argument in the receiving actor? That's not possible. Interpolation happens at compile time, so the variable has to be in scope at definition of the string.

Comment: Okay, thats exaclty what I wanted to know. Thanks! Then I better use a external Template-Engine.